# Sort XML nodes using specific order in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have the following XML:

```
<xml xmlns="http://xml.org">
    <A>
        <A>One</A>
        <B>Two</B>
        <C>Three</C>
    </A>
    <B>
        <A>One</A>
        <B>Two</B>
        <C>Three</C>
    </B>
    <C>
        <A>One</A>
        <B>Two</B>
        <C>Three</C>
    </C>
</xml>
```

I am trying to sort the child nodes in A, to be B A C, to get:

```
<xml xmlns="http://xml.org">
    <A>
        <B>Two</B>
        <A>One</A>
        <C>Three</C>
    </A>
    <B>
        <A>One</A>
        <B>Two</B>
        <C>Three</C>
    </B>
    <C>
        <A>One</A>
        <B>Two</B>
        <C>Three</C>
    </C>
</xml>
```

I'm not sure how to go about this, I tried doing this with the following lines:

```
my_own_order = ['B', 'A', 'C']
order = {key: i for i, key in enumerate(my_own_order)}

for node in f.xpath('//xmlns:xml/xmlns:A/*', namespaces={'xmlns': str(ns[None])}):
    node[:] = sorted(node, key=order)
```

But this didn't do anything at all. Am I on the right track with what I'm doing? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
#get all children in a nodelist
nodes=f.xpath('//xmlns:xml/xmlns:A/*', namespaces={'xmlns': str(ns[None])})
#sort nodelist
nodes= sorted(nodes, key=order)
#get parent A node
anode=nodes[0].parent
#remove unsorted children
for node in nodes:
    node.parent.remove(node)
# add sorted children
for node in nodes:
    anode.add(node)
```

Comment: Note that this solution will work on the assumption that there is only one A parent node.

Comment: I've simplified the code a bit more, let me know of any errors... as my Mac-excel doesn't have XML references available to test:-(